# Has anyone noticed that you cannot scale the emitter rocket booster?

Tags: rec-room

I used to be able to scale the emitter when it was set under the rocket booster. Now it stays the same size. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember whether I ever scaled an emitter. I think I always changed the scale of the particle system with the yellow input pin.

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the emitter but it doesn't change how it behaves. If you want the particles to be larger you'll need to change the size input on the emitter's yellow pin.